# Distinguish between sign up and login using LinkedIn OAuth in Meteor

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm using `pauli:accounts-linkedin` in my app to allow login with LinkedIn. But I need a way in the frontend to distinguish between a first time login (sign up) and subsequent logins with LinkedIn for the purposes of tracking sign ups.

I've looked at Meteor's `Accounts.onCreateUser` hook, but I need to track which LinkedIn login button was clicked in the UI which doesn't seem available to that hook.

The `Meteor.loginWithLinkedIn` provided by the package doesn't provide anything for `result` variable in the callback, which would be a nice place to provide a flag for that kind of thing.

[Distinguishing between Sign Up and Sign In with Meteor.loginWithExternalService()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613950/distinguishing-between-sign-up-and-sign-in-with-meteor-loginwithexternalservice) doesn't quite address the same issue.

Currently, it looks like my only course of action is to effectively "duck type" to check if this is the first login of the user when they log in with LinkedIn.